# Color guessing game does not loop when wrong

Tags: javascript

The issue here is this: every time I run this code, it works well but does not perform the while loop to iterate the game again when it's wrong and I can't find the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Color guessing game</title>
</head>

<body onload="do_game()">
    <script>
        var color = ["Black","Blue","Brown","Cyan","GoldenRod","Green","Maroon","Olive","Pink","Red"];
        var target;
        var finished = false;
        var guess_input;
        var guesses;

        function do_game() {
            var target_index = Math.random() * 10;
            var target = Math.floor(target_index);

            alert(color[target]);

            while(!finished) {
                guess_input = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors: \n\n" +
                                        "Black,Blue,Brown,Cyan,GoldenRod,Green, Maroon,Olive,Pink,Red \n\n"
                                        + "What color am i thinking of?");
                guesses +=1;
                finished = check_guess();
                }
        }

        myBody.style.background=name_of_color;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gah, no way to end the game... luckily there is a don't show any more alerts option :) but after that the page freeze due to `while(true) {waste cpu}` edit your code to check for abort or empty string to cancel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things missing in your question (we don't know what is check_guess??), but I tried to do some work and get you pretty close to what you're looking for. Hope this solution helps you.

```js
var color = ["Black", "Blue", "Brown", "Cyan", "GoldenRod", "Green", "Maroon", "Olive", "Pink", "Red"];
var target;
var finished = false;
var guess_input;
var guesses;
var randomComputerGuess;

function do_game() {
  var target_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

  alert(color[target_index]);
  randomComputerGuess = color[target_index];

  while (!finished) {
    guess_input = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors: \n\n" +
      "Black,Blue,Brown,Cyan,GoldenRod,Green, Maroon,Olive,Pink,Red \n\n" + "What color am i thinking of?");
    if (randomComputerGuess === guess_input) {
      alert("Good Job! You guessed it.");
      finished = true;
      //document.style.background=color[target_index];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="do_game()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You never defined the function `check_guess`.

When the browser tried to execute the code on that line, it issued an error and the script stopped.

Look for the "Developer Tools" or similar menu item in your browser and you will see the error displayed there.

My guess is also that your script has problems with the variables `myBody` and `name_of_color` which also do not appear in your script. But since you said "it works well" there are probably some things you are not showing us.